# Load table data from external file jQuery

Tags: jquery, html

I'm looking to pull a large set of table data from an external file into a table on a main index page. The code would essentially go something like

```
  <table>
      <tr>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Last</th>
      </tr>
        <div class="table-data"></div>   ##Insert data here##
   </table>
```

The external file would like this:

```
data.html

    <tr>
        <td>John</td>
        <td>Smith</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Mary</td>
        <td>Adams</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Joe</td>
        <td>Appleseed</td>
    </tr>
```

I've been trying to use jQuery and .load function along the lines of:

```
$(".table-data").load("data.html");
```

Potentially its more about using .get and .append ?

I'd be looking to do this with two different sets of external data on the same index page.

Any help, greatly appreciated.

(I realise the code doesn't actually work the way it is, I was just laying it out to see if anyone could help with a method forward).

The data.html file is a large file, and I'm trying to limit loading it in the first instance until it is triggered via a click/button.

Comment: `<div>` is invalid child of `<table>`. Use a `<tbody>` instead and `load()` should work just fine

Comment: Cheers, worked a treat, had to upload to a server to get the file to retrieve as well.. Thanks